# The meaning of the phrase "should they prove correct"

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Some of the strangest and, ***should they prove correct***, most revealing insights of modern physics...

Would you please explain what the phrase "should they prove correct" means in here? I even doubt it's grammatically acceptable, as it sounds like a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Should** in this context means **in case** or **if**. It's a more formal way of referring to a hypothesis.

So the meaning of your quotation is: **Some of the strangest and, *in case* they prove correct, most revealing insight of modern physics**.

Should you need more information on this structure, don't hesitate to ask (=In case you need...).